# Text overflow starting on two lines

Tags: html, css, angular

I have the following styles which I use in a table. If the text has more than one line, it only shows the first line and the rest are shown if the user hovers his mouse on the text.

The thing is that I want to show at least two lines if there are. Imagine that I have a text with 4 lines, the 2 first lines should  be shown since the begining and the other 2 when the user hovers his mouse over the text.

My current code is this:

```
.cortar {
  width: 135px !important;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cortar:hover {
  width: 100%;
  white-space: initial;
  overflow: visible;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

My html:

```
<p-table [columns]="columnasIndicadoresOperacion>
    <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup" let-columns>
        <colgroup>
           <col *ngFor="let col of columns">
        </colgroup>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
       <tr>
          <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
              {{col.header}}
          </th>
       </tr>
     </ng-template>
     <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
           <td class="cortar"*ngFor="let col of columns">
               <p [title]="rowData.indicadores[col.field]">
                   {{rowData.indicadores[col.field]}}
               </p>
           </td>
        </tr>
     </ng-template>
 </p-table>
```

Comment: Could you also add the relevant part of your HTML code to make this easier to test and answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `-webkit-line-clamp` as below:

```
.cortar {
  width: 135px !important;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   /* from here */
   box-sizing: border-box;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

In case its some scss file which is compiled you might need to add `autoprefixer`. I faced this while working with `angular`.

```
.cortar {
  width: 135px !important;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  -moz-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    /* autoprefixer: off */
    webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    /* autoprefixer: on */
}
```

[a demo code here](https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/PewgjE)

Comment: Just one thing need to take care is this is not supported in IE.

Comment: and if you need IE support as well then i will suggest use java script solution only with character limit.

Comment: it's an angular project, how to use autoprefixer? I never used that. I copied your .cortar code but it's showing the whole text

Comment: "display: -webkit-box;" seems to break lots of things, now stuff look like with a very small width :/

Comment: I don't know if it's because I am using a table or something else, but that's not working :/ I've edited my original post with the html code

Comment: @UlisesCT : Would you please replicate this on https://stackblitz.com/ . I'll take from there. It seems more like an global styling issue of your app. If you can replicate on the demo code then I can help you more on this.

Comment: @UlisesCT : Cheers mate !